# Find the suitable vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Consider $\lbrace \vec{B}_{1},\vec{B}_{2},\ldots,\vec{B}_{n}\rbrace$ be a set of $n>2$ three-dimensional non-unit vectors. My question is can I find a unit vector $\hat{A}$ such that,

$$\hat{A}.\vec{B}_{1}=\hat{A}.\vec{B}_{2}=\hat{A}.\vec{B}_{3}=\hat{A}.\vec{B}_{4}=\ldots=\hat{A}.\vec{B}_{n}$$

For $n=3$, I can easily obtain

$$\hat{A}=\frac{\vec{B}_{1}\times\vec{B}_{2}+\vec{B}_{2}\times\vec{B}_{3}+\vec{B}_{3}\times\vec{B}_{1}}{||\vec{B}_{1}\times\vec{B}_{2}+\vec{B}_{2}\times\vec{B}_{3}+\vec{B}_{3}\times\vec{B}_{1}||}$$

However, what I want is a general construction of $\hat{A}$ for arbitrary $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement that $A$ has length 1 can be replaced by the requirement that $A$ is nonzero, because then if you have found a solution you can always divide by the norm, and it will remain a solution.

Define an $(n-1)\times n$ matrix $M$ with elements $M_{ij}=(B_{i+1}-B_i)_j$, $i=1,2,\ldots n-1$, $j=1,2,\ldots n$. Remove the $j_0$'th column to convert $M$ into a square matrix ${M}^{(j_0)}$ of size $(n-1)\times(n-1)$. Which column you remove does not matter, provided that the determinant of ${M}^{(j_0)}$ is nonzero. The elements of the removed column form a vector $v$ of length $n-1$. Solve the set of $n-1$ linear equations for the $n-1$ unknowns $a_j$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}M_{ij}^{(j_0)}a_j=v_i,\;\;i=1,2,\ldots n-1.$$
The solution is given by [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule),
$$a_i=\frac{\det X^{(i)}}{\det M^{(j_0)}},$$
where the matrix $X^{(i)}$ is obtained by replacing the $i$-th column of $M^{(j_0)}$ by the column vector $v$.

Now the desired vector $A$ has elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots a_{j_0-1},-1,a_{j_0},\ldots a_{n-1}$. Divide by the norm to obtain a unit vector, and you're done.

Comment: Aplogies for late reply. Shouldn't $j$ run from $1$ to $3$ as we are only confining ourselves to the three-dimensional vectors In that case, for $i>3$ is the system of equations are overdetermined and no solution will be present.

Comment: indeed, you need $n$ vectors of length $n$ if you wish to find a solution when the vectors $B_i$ are distinct.